# Call a service from @ngModule

Tags: angular, module

I want to call a service imported in my @ngModule from a login component.
This what i did but it's not working. 
I have just started to work on the A2 final version.

```
export class Login implements OnInit{
  constructor(
    private _service: Service
    ) {
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this._service.login(value)
        .subscribe(x => console.log(x));
    }
  }
}
```

My @ngModule

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginService } from '../service/login.service'; 

import { Login } from './login.component';

export const routes = [
  { path: '', component: Login, pathMatch: 'full' }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    Login
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  providers: [LoginService]
})
export default class LoginModule {
  static routes = routes;
}
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: A hint from the style guide: "Avoid prefixing private properties and methods with an underscore." https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#style-03-04

Answer (score 1):

Inside constructor `Service` should be `LoginService`, as you wanted to access/create an instance of `LoginService`. Also make sure `LoginService` has been imported.

```
constructor(
   private _service: LoginService //<-- changed dependency type name
   ) {
}
```

Comment: I get this : Error: Can't resolve all parameters for Login: (Router, ?).

Comment: @AdrienCastagliola do you have `router-outlet` directive on page..?

Answer (score 1):

Chage your component class to use `LoginService`

```
export class Login implements OnInit{
  constructor(
    private _service: LoginService
    ) {
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this._service.login(value)
        .subscribe(x => console.log(x));
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to import LoginService in Login component also and add it to constructor as:

```
constructor( _service: LoginService) {  }
```